# как в webpack при билде сделать читаемый js?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack4

Можно ли избавиться от `webpack` модулей в `main.js`?
Или есть ещё какие-то методы , чтобы сделать мой код на выходе читаемым?
Добавил свой пример и то что получается на выходе.
В конфиге по дефолту встроен `jquery` и бандл разбивается на `vendors.js` и `main.js`

```js
module.exports = function () {
  return {
    //..
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        minSize: 0
      },
      minimizer: [
        //сжатие файлов *.min.js ,в моем случае файлов, из node_modules
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
          sourceMap: true,
          include: /\.min\.js$/,
        }),
         //настройки сжатия для моего кода
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
          sourceMap: true,
          uglifyOptions: {
            compress: false,
            mangle: false,
            output: { beautify: true },
          },
          include: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /\.min\.js$/
        }),
      ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ]
  }
}
```

В моем файле
`// main.js`
`$(document).ready(function () {console.log('1')})`
А на выходе:

```js
(function(modules) {
    function webpackJsonpCallback(data) {
        var chunkIds = data[0];
        var moreModules = data[1];
        var executeModules = data[2];
        var moduleId, chunkId, i = 0, resolves = [];
        for (;i < chunkIds.length; i++) {
            chunkId = chunkIds[i];
            if (installedChunks[chunkId]) {
                resolves.push(installedChunks[chunkId][0]);
            }
            installedChunks[chunkId] = 0;
        }
        for (moduleId in moreModules) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(moreModules, moduleId)) {
                modules[moduleId] = moreModules[moduleId];
            }
        }
        if (parentJsonpFunction) parentJsonpFunction(data);
        while (resolves.length) {
            resolves.shift()();
        }
        deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
        return checkDeferredModules();
    }
    function checkDeferredModules() {
        var result;
        for (var i = 0; i < deferredModules.length; i++) {
            var deferredModule = deferredModules[i];
            var fulfilled = true;
            for (var j = 1; j < deferredModule.length; j++) {
                var depId = deferredModule[j];
                if (installedChunks[depId] !== 0) fulfilled = false;
            }
            if (fulfilled) {
                deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
                result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    var installedModules = {};
    var installedChunks = {
        0: 0
    };
    var deferredModules = [];
    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
        if (installedModules[moduleId]) {
            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
        }
        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
            i: moduleId,
            l: false,
            exports: {}
        };
        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
        module.l = true;
        return module.exports;
    }
    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
        if (!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
                enumerable: true,
                get: getter
            });
        }
    };
    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
        if (typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && Symbol.toStringTag) {
            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, {
                value: "Module"
            });
        }
        Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
            value: true
        });
    };
    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
        if (mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
        if (mode & 8) return value;
        if (mode & 4 && typeof value === "object" && value && value.__esModule) return value;
        var ns = Object.create(null);
        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
        Object.defineProperty(ns, "default", {
            enumerable: true,
            value: value
        });
        if (mode & 2 && typeof value != "string") for (var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) {
            return value[key];
        }.bind(null, key));
        return ns;
    };
    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
        var getter = module && module.__esModule ? function getDefault() {
            return module["default"];
        } : function getModuleExports() {
            return module;
        };
        __webpack_require__.d(getter, "a", getter);
        return getter;
    };
    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property);
    };
    __webpack_require__.p = "";
    var jsonpArray = window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || [];
    var oldJsonpFunction = jsonpArray.push.bind(jsonpArray);
    jsonpArray.push = webpackJsonpCallback;
    jsonpArray = jsonpArray.slice();
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonpArray.length; i++) webpackJsonpCallback(jsonpArray[i]);
    var parentJsonpFunction = oldJsonpFunction;
    deferredModules.push([ 0, 1 ]);
    return checkDeferredModules();
})([ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
    __webpack_require__(1);
    module.exports = __webpack_require__(5);
}, function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {
    "use strict";
    __webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
    (function($) {
        var _styles_main_sass__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(3);
        var _styles_main_sass__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = __webpack_require__.n(_styles_main_sass__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("1");
        });
    }).call(this, __webpack_require__(2));
}, , function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {} ]);
//# sourceMappingURL=main.0.js.map
```

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, а зачем?

Comment: @andreymal просто я пытаюсь понять как редактировать минифицированный код без помощи сборок? получается мне из source надо копировать все модули и потом прогонять его через транспилятор?

Comment: Он не предназначен для редактирования, просто редактируйте исходники и собирайте как обычно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    //сжатие файлов *.min.js ,в моем случае файлов, из node_modules
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      include: /\.min\.js$/,
    }),
```

Зачем вы сжимаете файлы, которые уже и так сжаты?

```
   new UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: false,
        mangle: false,
        output: { beautify: true },
      },
      include: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /\.min\.js$/
    }),
```

Чем вам соурсмапы не подошли? Вы в любом случае получите нечитаемый код, так как минифицируете его.

То что добавляет вебпак - это реализация модуля и ленивой подгрузки. Это необходимый код, иначе ваши модули не будут работать. Не обращайте на это внимание. Посмотреть ваш код вы можете во вкладке `source` девтулзов, там будет папочка с исходным кодом

Comment: Возможно это глупый вопрос, т.к я недавно пользуюсь webpack ,но исходный код получается уже не редактируемый? т.е если мне нужно поменять переменную или удалить функцию, получается надо копировать все модули и прогонять их через транспилятор?

Comment: @beaviz0405 да. Только о каком копировании речь — непонятно, ничего не надо копировать при нормальной сборке

Comment: @andreymal, имел ввиду вкладку source. Получается если кому-то понадобится отредактировать мой код, то без сборки у них ничего не получится

Comment: @beaviz0405 те, кому понадобится отредактировать код, по-хорошему сделают git clone и git checkout -b :) И потом соберут, да

Comment: @beaviz0405 и вообще здесь примерно применимы принципы как для обычных компилируемых языков программирования, скомпилированный бинарный файлик в каком-нибудь C++ тоже затруднительно изменить без исходника